# How would one construct a complex/composite controller for multiple controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new to OOP/MVC and I do have a basic understanding of a controller which interacts with an underlying model. Basically, a controller acts as a "CRUD gateway" to a model. However, consider an e-commerce marketplace object: Order.

An e-commerce order in a marketplace would interact with multiple tables and hence an order can be thought of as a join of multiple tables: *orders, order_items, order_sellers, order_buyer (and more perhaps).*

If I understand it correctly, each one of these tables would have a controller allowing CRUD operations (OrderInfoController, OrderItemController,OrderSellerController,OrderBuyerController etc.).

However, could I also create a controller for 'Orders' which then instantiates the Controller Object for each of the tables involved in an Order?

```
OrderController {
  $this->orderInfo = OrderInfo Object;
  $this->orderItems = array of Order Item Objects;
  $this->orderSellers = array of Order Seller Objects;
  $this->orderBuyer = OrderBuyer Object;

  function create($arr_order)
     //create the order object by calling each of the member controllers.

  function get($orderId)
    //get the complete order by order Id....

  function update($orderId)
    
  function delete($orderId)

}
```

I have gone through a few MVC docs but I have not come across a solution to this problem. My question is then: Is this the correct approach to write a controller which interacts with multiple tables?

Answer (score 0):

To

> If I understand it correctly, each one of these tables would have a controller allowing CRUD operations [...].

In a web MVC-based application, each request is, indeed, served by a *controller* (the *"C"* in *"MVC"*).

Though, the controller delegates the whole processing of the request to one or more *application services* (e.g. *use cases*, e.g *actions* - see resources list below), as part of the [*service layer*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). These services interact with the *model* (the *"M"* in *"MVC"*), e.g. [*domain model*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html), e.g. *model layer*, which, in turn, interact with the database.

The final result of the processing of the request data, e.g. the *response* object, is either returned to the controller, in order to be passed and printed on screen by the *view* (the *"V"* in *"MVC"*), or directly to the view, for the same reason.

After watching both videos in the resources list below, you will understand, that **the model doesn't need to know anything about the database**. So, the components of the model layer (mostly interfaces) should not know where and how the data passed to them by the services is saved. Therefore, **the services and the controllers should also know nothing about the database**.

All informations regarding the database should be located in [*data mappers*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) only - as part of the *infrastructure layer*. These objects should be the only ones understanding the database API. Therefore, the only ones containing and beeing able to execute SQL statements.

To

> Is this the correct approach to write a controller which interacts with multiple tables?

No. But it's not a problem. Just keep learning about MVC.

**Resources:**

- [Keynote: Architecture the Lost Years](https://confreaks.tv/videos/rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years) by Robert Martin.
- [Sandro Mancuso : Crafted Design](https://vimeo.com/107963074)

---

Here is some code of mine. At first sight, it's maybe a lot of it, but I'm confident, that it will help you to better understand.

For simplicity, follow the definition of the method `getAllUsers` in the view class `SampleMvc\App\View\Template\Users\Users`.

First of all, here is *a not so important note (yet)*: In my code, the controller only updates the model layer, and the view only fetches data from the model layer. Only the response returned by the view is, therefore, printed. The controller and the view are called by a class `RouteInvoker`, like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyPackages\Framework\Routing;

//...

class RouteInvoker implements RouteInvokerInterface {

    //...

    public function invoke(RouteInterface $route): ResponseInterface {
        $controller = $this->resolveController($route);
        $view = $this->resolveView($route);

        $parameters = $route->getParameters();

        $this->callableInvoker->call($controller, $parameters);

        return $this->callableInvoker->call($view, $parameters);
    }

    //...

}
```

The result (`$response`) of `RouteInvoker:invoke` is printed like this:

```
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

And from here follows an example of a code invoked by `RouteInvoker:invoke`:

**A controller to handle the users:**

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Controller\Users;

use function sprintf;
use SampleMvc\App\Service\Users\{
    Users as UserService,
    Exception\UserExists,
};
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

/**
 * A controller to handle the users.
 */
class Users {

    /**
     * 
     * @param UserService $userService A service to handle the users.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private UserService $userService
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Add a user.
     * 
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request A server request.
     * @return void
     */
    public function addUser(ServerRequestInterface $request): void {
        $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];

        try {
            $this->userService->addUser($username);    
        } catch (UserExists $exception) {
            //...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove all users.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeAllUsers(): void {
        $this->userService->removeAllUsers();
    }

}
```

**A view to handle the users:**

Notice, that controller and view share the same `UserService` instance.

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\View\Template\Users;

use SampleMvc\App\{
    View\Layout\Primary,
    Service\Users\Users as UserService,
    Components\Service\MainNavigation,
};
use Psr\Http\Message\{
    ResponseInterface,
    ResponseFactoryInterface,
};
use AlePackages\Template\Renderer\TemplateRendererInterface;

/**
 * A view to handle the users.
 */
class Users extends Primary {

    /**
     * 
     * @param UserService $userService A service to handle the users.
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory,
        TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer,
        MainNavigation $mainNavigationService,
        private UserService $userService
    ) {
        parent::__construct($responseFactory, $templateRenderer, $mainNavigationService);
    }

    /**
     * Display the list of users.
     * 
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function default(): ResponseInterface {
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Users/Users.html.twig', [
            'activeNavItem' => 'Users',
            'users' => $this->getAllUsers(),
        ]);

        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Add a user.
     * 
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function addUser(): ResponseInterface {
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Users/Users.html.twig', [
            'activeNavItem' => 'Users',
            'message' => 'User successfully added',
            'users' => $this->getAllUsers(),
        ]);

        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Remove all users.
     * 
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function removeAllUsers(): ResponseInterface {
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Users/Users.html.twig', [
            'activeNavItem' => 'Users',
            'message' => 'All users successfully removed',
            'users' => $this->getAllUsers(),
        ]);

        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of users.
     * 
     * @return (string|int)[][] The list of users.
     */
    private function getAllUsers(): array {
        $users = $this->userService->findAllUsers();
        $usersFormatted = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $usersFormatted[] = [
                'id' => $user->getId(),
                'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            ];
        }

        return $usersFormatted;
    }

}
```

**A service to handle the users:**

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Service\Users;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\User\{
    User,
    UserCollection,
};
use SampleMvc\App\Service\Users\Exception\UserExists;

/**
 * A service to handle the users.
 */
class Users {

    /**
     * 
     * @param UserCollection $userCollection A collection of users.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private UserCollection $userCollection
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Find a user by id.
     * 
     * @param int $id An id.
     * @return User|null The found user or null.
     */
    public function findUserById(int $id): ?User {
        return $this->userCollection->findById($id);
    }

    /**
     * Find all users.
     * 
     * @return User[] The list of users.
     */
    public function findAllUsers(): array {
        return $this->userCollection->all();
    }

    /**
     * Add a user.
     * 
     * @param string|null $username A username.
     * @return User The added user.
     */
    public function addUser(?string $username): User {
        $user = $this->createUser($username);

        return $this->storeUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all users.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeAllUsers(): void {
        $this->userCollection->clear();
    }

    /**
     * Create a user.
     * 
     * @param string|null $username A username.
     * @return User The user.
     */
    private function createUser(?string $username): User {
        $user = new User();

        $user->setUsername($username);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Store a user.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return User The stored user.
     * @throws UserExists A user already exists.
     */
    private function storeUser(User $user): User {
        if ($this->userCollection->exists($user)) {
            throw new UserExists('Username "' . $user->getUsername() . '" already used');
        }

        return $this->userCollection->store($user);
    }

}
```

**An exception indicating that a user already exists:**

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Service\Users\Exception;

/**
 * An exception indicating that a user already exists.
 */
class UserExists extends \OverflowException {
    
}
```

**An interface to a collection of users:**

Notice, that this is an interface.

Notice, that this interface is a component of the [*domain model*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)!

Notice, that its implementation (e.g. `SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Repository\User\UserCollection` further down below) is not part of the domain model, but of the *infrastructure layer*!

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Model\User;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\User\User;

/**
 * An interface to a collection of users.
 */
interface UserCollection {

    /**
     * Find a user by id.
     * 
     * @param int $id An id.
     * @return User|null The found user or null.
     */
    public function findById(int $id): ?User;

    /**
     * Get all users from the collection.
     * 
     * @return User[] All users in the collection.
     */
    public function all(): array;

    /**
     * Store a user.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return User The stored user.
     */
    public function store(User $user): User;

    /**
     * Check if a user exists in the collection.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return bool True if the user exists, or false otherwise.
     */
    public function exists(User $user): bool;

    /**
     * Remove all users from the collection.
     * 
     * @return static
     */
    public function clear(): static;
}
```

**A collection of users:**

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Repository\User;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\User\{
    User,
    UserCollection as UserCollectionInterface,
};
use SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\User\UserMapper;

/**
 * A collection of users.
 */
class UserCollection implements UserCollectionInterface {

    /**
     * 
     * @param UserMapper $userMapper A user mapper.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private UserMapper $userMapper
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function findById(int $id): ?User {
        return $this->userMapper->fetchUserById($id);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function all(): array {
        return $this->userMapper->fetchAllUsers();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function store(User $user): User {
        return $this->userMapper->saveUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function exists(User $user): bool {
        return $this->userMapper->userExists($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function clear(): static {
        $this->userMapper->deleteAllUsers();
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**An interface to a user mapper:**

Notice that this is the interface of a [*data mapper*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\User;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\User\User;

/**
 * An interface to a user mapper.
 */
interface UserMapper {

    /**
     * Fetch a user by id.
     * 
     * Note: PDOStatement::fetch returns FALSE if no record is found.
     * 
     * @param int $id A user id.
     * @return User|null The user or null.
     */
    public function fetchUserById(int $id): ?User;

    /**
     * Fetch all users.
     * 
     * @return User[] The list of users.
     */
    public function fetchAllUsers(): array;

    /**
     * Save a user.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return User The saved user.
     */
    public function saveUser(User $user): User;

    /**
     * Check if a user exists.
     * 
     * Note: PDOStatement::fetch returns FALSE if no record is found.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return bool True if the user exists, or false otherwise.
     */
    public function userExists(User $user): bool;

    /**
     * Delete all users.
     * 
     * @return static
     */
    public function deleteAllUsers(): static;
}
```

**A PDO user mapper:**

Notice, that this component is the implementation of a [*data mapper*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Notice, that this component is the only one understanding the database API. Therefore, the only one containing and beeing able to execute SQL statements.

Notice, that this component is not part of the [*domain model*](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html), but of the *infrastructure layer*!

(1) Notice, that **you can write any SQL statements that you want, including JOIN statements**. So, the fetched data can come from multiple tables as well.

(2) Notice also, that the result of a method of this class could be **a list of objects of a type defined by you (!), independent of the underlying table(s) data.**.

The conclusion from (1) and (2) above: **The database structure does NOT affect in any way the way in which your application is structured**.

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\User;

use SampleMvc\Domain\{
    Model\User\User,
    Infrastructure\Mapper\User\UserMapper,
};
use PDO;

/**
 * A PDO user mapper.
 */
class PdoUserMapper implements UserMapper {

    /**
     * 
     * @param PDO $connection A database connection.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private PDO $connection
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function fetchUserById(int $id): ?User {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            'id' => $id,
        ]);

        $dataArray = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return ($dataArray === false) ? null : $this->convertDataArrayToUser($dataArray);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function fetchAllUsers(): array {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        $listOfDataArrays = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->convertListOfDataArraysToListOfUsers($listOfDataArrays);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function saveUser(User $user): User {
        return $this->insertUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function userExists(User $user): bool {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM users WHERE username = :username';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            ':username' => $user->getUsername(),
        ]);

        $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return ($data['cnt'] > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function deleteAllUsers(): static {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM users';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Insert a user.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return User The user, with updated id.
     */
    private function insertUser(User $user): User {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (:username)';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            ':username' => $user->getUsername(),
        ]);

        $user->setId($this->connection->lastInsertId());

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Update a user.
     * 
     * @param User $user A user.
     * @return User The user.
     */
    private function updateUser(User $user): User {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET username = :username WHERE id = :id';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            ':username' => $user->getUsername(),
            ':id' => $user->getId(),
        ]);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given data array to a user.
     * 
     * @param array $dataArray A data array.
     * @return User The user.
     */
    private function convertDataArrayToUser(array $dataArray): User {
        $user = new User();

        $user
            ->setId($dataArray['id'])
            ->setUsername($dataArray['username'])
        ;

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given list of data arrays to a list of users.
     * 
     * @param array[] $listOfDataArrays A list of data arrays.
     * @return User[] The list of users.
     */
    private function convertListOfDataArraysToListOfUsers(array $listOfDataArrays): array {
        $listOfUsers = [];

        foreach ($listOfDataArrays as $dataArray) {
            $listOfUsers[] = $this->convertDataArrayToUser($dataArray);
        }

        return $listOfUsers;
    }

}
```